# Prove that $\overline{C}-C$ is a compact set if $C$ is compact subset in a metric space $(X,d)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I havee to prove that if $C$ is a compact subset in a metric space $(X,d)$ then $\overline{C}-C$ is compact.

**My idea**. I supposed that $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I}  \ A_\alpha \subset \overline{C}-C$ but I don't know how to continue, can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ is a topological vector space or a topological abelian group? Otherwise, is the minus set complement?

Comment: Compact sets in metric spaces are closed. So $\bar C - C$ is empty (and so trivially compact).